# how to get value from json object with its index number in reactjs like posts[2].title

Tags: json, reactjs

from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
{  this.state.posts.map((post) => {
       return (
                <li>
                    <span>{post.title}</span>
                 </li>
              );
          })
       }
```

it return all the title but how do I get post[1] or post[0] title
tried {post[0].title} not working

Thank you

Comment: post[0].title should work. just dont put it inside any loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the map function and simply write

```js
<li>
   <span>{this.state.posts[0].title}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Yes, it would work only if posts are available in your state. In case you need to wait for them to be available you need to add a check for that line, like:

<span>{this.state.posts[0] ? this.state.posts[0].title : ''}</span>

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the index with post inside function, it will help us to iterate over list of post.

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
       <li>
           <span>{post[index].title}</span>
       </li>
   })
}
```

return should be before the map if you need it.

```
return (
    {this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
           <li>
               <span>{post[index].title}</span>
           </li>
       })
    }
)
```